# Messages not received on first time connection

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am unable to receive messages on first time connection. for in more detail,`user A` is connected and publishing messages,but `user B` is not connected to that topic.So when `user B` will connect,he will not get any message from user A because there is first time connection b/w `user a` and `user b`.

How we can resolve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: userB must have connected at least one time with cleanSession=false before it will start to receive QoS>0 msgs. It can disconnect after the initial connection. But new clients coming in will not magically receive these msgs. An initial connection with cleanSession=false is required. What framework / client / broker are you using ?

Comment: we are using moscapsule and mosquitto broker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A principle of pub/sub is that the publisher and subscriber are decoupled, so you shouldn't really be thinking in terms of `user a` being connected to `user b`.

If you want a client to receive messages when they are not connected (leaving retained messages to one side), the only way to do this is:

- Connect beforehand with `cleansession=false`
- Subscribe with QoS>0 (or on mosquitto use the `queue_qos0_messages` option)
- Ensure that messages are published with QoS>0
- When the client reconnects, use `cleansession=false`

To test this, try:

```
mosquitto_sub -i prajbot-singh -h test.mosquitto.org -t prajbot-singh -c -q 1
```

Then quit from mosquitto_sub and run:

```
mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t prajbot-singh -m hello -q 1
```

And run mosquitto_sub again:

```
mosquitto_sub -i prajbot-singh -h test.mosquitto.org -t prajbot-singh -c -q 1
```